# PHP: If $timestamp is older than 12 weeks then…

Tags: php, date, comparison, timestamp

`echo ($timestamp)` gives `"2012-05-03 15:35:46"`

What would a PHP command look like that does:`"if $timestamp is older than 12 weeks then…"`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No effort or web search done!

Comment: Look up the `time()` function, which might be useful to you. Along with the `date()` function and the `strtotime()` function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the fastest way of doing it in PHP in term of micro optimisation.

```
if(strtotime($timestamp) <= time() - (60*60*24*7*12)){
    // 60 secs * 60 mins * 24 hours * 7 days * 12 weeks
}
```

Please go read about [strtotime](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php) to know how to convert timestamp to unixtime. Also read about [time](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.time.php) function.

Comment: @Xavier No problem ! Next time, do more research.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is [`strtotime()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)!

```
$timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
$twelveWeeksAgo = strtotime('-12 weeks');

if($timestamp < $twelveWeeksAgo) {
 // do something
}
```

There are multiple ways of checking this, this is the most explanatory at a glance IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_to_compare  = new DateTime();
$twelve_weeks_ago = new DateTime ("-12 weeks");
if ($time_to_compare < $twelve_weeks_ago)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php > 5.2, you can use DateTime and DateInterval objects:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$before = bew DateTime("2012-05-03 15:35:46");

$diff = $now->diff($before);

if ($diff->d > (12 * 7)) {
    print "Older than 12 weeks";
}
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) the documentation of the above objects.